# Using PDO In A Object

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

#### So Far

```
class PDOExtender
{
    private $_DBO;
    public function openConnection()
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME;
        $this->_DBO = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    }
}
```

I'm aware that the class is not actually extending the pdo object, i don't know why i called it that.

#### My Question

I need to add the this class so that I can make some queries, in particular using prepared statements. Can someone give me feed back on what to add to accomplish this.
I am currently calling this class from inside another class like this,

```
$this->_siteRegistry = Registry::singleton();
$this->_siteRegistry->storeObject("PDOExtender", "DBO");
$this->_DBO = $this->_siteRegistry->getObject("DBO");
try {
    $this->_DBO->openConnection();
} catch(Exception $e) {
throw new Exception("server");
}
```

#### My Old Way, Without PDO

In my old projects i just used mysql, but i created the code myself and i'm sure its not the best way to get things done so i'd rather not just use the code i have with pdo integrated.
This is it,

```
public function runQuery($query, $functionArray = array(), $needResults)
{
    $stmtParam = "";
    $parameters = array();
    $results = array();
    foreach ($functionArray as $v) {
        $stmtParam .= "s";
    }
    array_unshift($functionArray, $stmtParam);
    $stmt = $this->_dbConnection->prepare($query);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $functionArray);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($needResults) {
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
        while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {
            $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
        while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $x = array();  
            foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {
                $x[$key] = $val;
            }
            $results[] = $x; 
        }
        return $results;
    } else return true;
}
```

#### To Finish

i need help converting my old code to use with pdo.
IF anyone knows of any great tutorials which show how to do this please link them, I did look but couldn't find any.

Thank you for your time
Chris

Comment: 1. What do you have that's not working? 2. Why do you feel the need to wrap PDO - a class - inside another class? What functionality is it missing that you intend to add?

Comment: @Erick i think that the fact that he's now using the singleton pattern will improve the performance since he won't initialize the connection for each query. cheers!

Comment: @pleasedontbelong if you need to initialize connection for each query, then you are simply **doing it wrong** (tm). Besides, [singletons are evil](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Comment: @teresko that's what i said =) initializing the connection is a common problem on web developpers (at least the ones i know). The video applies mostly to Java developpment, where you could have instances that are Application Wide.. while in Php every request is a "main()".. and like the video said "there's nothing wrong with having a single instance of something, it becomes a problem when it's tight to a global state".. and i guess that the DB connection is a good candidate for a singleton pattern :) at least in php

Comment: @pleasedontbelong Nothing ever is a good candidate for singleton. You should provide same connection object to all the object which require it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also a singleton class for the db connection, you might want to checkit:

```
class DBConnection extends Singleton{

    private $connexion_pdo=null;

    protected function initialize(){
        $this->connexion_pdo = null;
        try{
            $this->connexion_pdo = new PDO(PDO_DSN,PDO_USR,PDO_PSW);
        }
        catch(PDOException $erreur){
            throw new Exception($erreur->getMessage());
        }
        $this->connexion_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->connexion_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
    }


    public function execute($query,$values=array()){
        try {
            $this->connexion_pdo->beginTransaction();
            $prepare_execute = $this->getPDOStatement($query);
            $prepare_execute->execute($values);
            $this->connexion_pdo->commit();
        } catch(PDOException $erreur){
            throw new Exception($erreur->getMessage());
        }
    }


    public function executeQuery($query,$values=array()){
        try {
            $resp = array();
            //$this->connexion_pdo->beginTransaction();
            $prepare_execute = $this->getPDOStatement($query);
            $prepare_execute->execute($values);
            $resp = $prepare_execute->fetchAll();
            //$this->connexion_pdo->commit();
            return $resp;
        } catch(PDOException $erreur){
            throw new Exception($erreur->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getPDOStatement($query){
        try {
            $prepare_execute = null;
            $prepare_execute = $this->connexion_pdo->prepare($query,array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
            return $prepare_execute; 
        } catch(PDOException $erreur){
            throw new Exception($erreur->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I use ´execute()´ for INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE, and the ´executeQuery()´ for the SELECT's. I know this code could be improved, but the main idea is there =D

I've seen that you're using a *while* loop to transform the result of the query.. i'd suggest you to create another class that manages that. There must be a class that asks the database, and another one that maps the results to what you need (an array, an object, etc)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can set PDO class as parameter of your class constructor.

Example:

```
$pdo = "...connect... & etc.";
$myClass = new MyClass($parameters, $pdo);

MyClass:

class MyClass {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($parameters, $pdo) {
         $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
}
```

and now you can use PDO in class AS $this->pdo->query & etc.